# grids of graphs in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Using the AXIS notation for matplotlib has allowed me to manually plot a grid of 2x2 or 3x3 or whatever size grid (if I know what size grid I want beforehand.)

However, how do you determine what size grid is needed automatically. Like what if you don't know how many unique values are in a column that you want to graph?

I am thinking there must be a way of doing this in a loop and figuring out based on the number of unique values in the column this is how big the graph needs to be.

**Example**

When I plot this for some reason it doesn't show month_name on the x axis (as in Jan, Feb, Marc etc)

```
avg_all_account.plot(legend=False,subplots=True,x='month_date',figsize=(10,20))
plt.xlabel('month')
plt.ylabel('number of proposals')
```

Yet when I plot subplots on a figure and specify x axis paremeter x='month_name' The month name appears on the plot here:

```
f = plt.figure()
f.set_figheight(8)
f.set_figwidth(8)
f.sharex=True
f.sharey=True

#graph1 = f.add_subplot(2,2,1)
avg_all_account.ix[0:,['month_date','number_open_proposals_all']].plot(ax=f.add_subplot(331),legend=False,subplots=True,x='month_date',y='number_open_proposals_all',title='open proposals')
plt.xlabel('month')
plt.ylabel('number of proposals')
```

Thus because the subplot method worked and showed the month_name on the x axis, and my x and y axis labels: I wanted to know how would I work out how many subplots I would need without first calculating it, then writing out each line and hard coding the subplot position?

Comment: What kind of data do you have? If you have panda DataFrame you can use the `pandas.unique()` or `pandas.nunique()` functions. Sounds like you want to make a faceted plot, so just use seaborn http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/faceted_histogram.html

Comment: unsolicited feedback: we can't read your mind as to what you data look like and how you're actually going to plot it. you're much more likely to get a meaningful answer if you put some effort into generation a runnable example and the ask about how to generalize it.

Comment: Paul thanks yes a facetplot would work except that when i try and plot month name i.e jan feb etc there is a bug that doesn't plot the month names in the right order even though they are sorted. I've then tried month-date ---> is there a way of setting the x axis position to vertical 2014-06-11 etc is very squished up. And doesn't fit. I've tried using mat plot lib subplots = true. Can you take what's in the legend and put it in the title instead???

Comment: did you read my second comment?